# Underscorejs: How to remove the outer array (square brackets)?

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

This is my Input:
[[2,3,5],[3,5],[4,5]]

I need this Output:
[2,3,5],[3,5],[4,5]

I'm not sure how to go about this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just need output like in this form as string??

Comment: [2,3,5],[3,5],[4,5] is not a valid json object. You should wrap it in an array as first case or keep the 3 sub arrays in different objects.

Answer (score 0):

`_.flatten` might be what you want.

Comment: I have already tried this, but this is not helpful for me. Thanks